# Phone Number Input Format with E.164 — Example: "+12133734253

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, libphonenumber

I'm using formik for my forms and I'm using this phone number validator/formatter https://catamphetamine.github.io/libphonenumber-js/

I want to format the number inputted by the user in E.164 format — Example: "+12133734253 regardless of the user will try to input arbitrary values like 12133734253

See my DEMO here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-faraday-3yzld

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the following Regex code in your input

```
/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```

see example
https://regex101.com/r/jAoKjO/1

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted to achieve but thanks!